# Add minimize and maximize buttons in Debian 8

Tags: debian, terminal, gnome

In previous versions I could do this with 
`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout close,minimize,maximize:`
but now I get error `no such key "button-layout"`
In GUI there is no `button-layout` in dconf-editor

So how can I add maximize and minimize buttons in Debian 8?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was looking for the same and shortly after reading this question I found the solution for my setup (Debian 8, Gnome-Flashback): The relevant key is in org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences, "button-layout". Edited with dconf-editor from "appmenu:close" to "appmenu:minimize,maximize,close" and the buttons are back :-)

Regards, Joachim

Comment: Another +1; there's a lot of out-of-date info on the web out there, this one does actually work on my Jessie with gnome flashback.

Comment: So does this mean: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout appmenu:minimize,maximize,close`? Could you put that into a command someone can use?

Comment: @Zelphir: I've tested your command on Debian 9 "Stretch" with Gnome 3.22.2 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize

For window buttons, I use Preference > Windows and have just the "Close" button on left side of the window. This fails for ALL GNOME applications, like Nautilus, Calculator, Gedit . .

or Gnome-shell and use the [tweak-tool](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gnome-tweak-tool).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

On debian 10, simply open a terminal and paste :

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ":minimize,maximize,close"
```